# Распределение ресурсов между фиксированным кол-вом получателем с неравными долями

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Пишу систему, распределяющую внутриигровую валюту между участниками конкурса.

Количество валюты, которое необходимо распределить известно, количество участников естественно тоже.

Распределение должно быть согласно правилам:

- Должны быть не равные доли для участников
- Ни у кого не должно совпадать кол-во валюты
- Распределено должно быть ровно имеющееся кол-во валюты

Помогите найти/составить алгоритм, который позволил бы провести такое распределение.

P.S. Задачу можно решить если просто выдавать каждому по 50% от остатка валюты для выдачи, но в таком случае получается слишком "резкий" график. Надо более равномерное распределение.

Comment: График чего? И что значит "резкий"? И какие ещё у вас требования, которые вы не написали? Где ваши попытки решить вашу задачу?

Comment: Возьмите формулу для арифметической прогрессии. И из неё в обратную сторону посчитайте либо приращение, зная начальную сумму и конечную, либо начальную сумму, задав приращение и конечный результат.

Comment: График распределения валюты между участниками. Мы можем представить это в виде графика взяв за ось X порядковый номер участника и за ось Y кол-во валюты, которое получит каждый конечный участник. Идея с арифметической прогрессией достаточно хорошая, попробую реализовать.